# Determine value so the improper integral has a maximum value

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have this improper integral =

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}\cos x dx
\end{equation}

I need to find for what a-value the integral will have a maximum value. a of course has to be:
\begin{equation}
a>0
\end{equation}
I have tried differentiating the integral and putting it equal to zero to find critical values and then solve for a, but all I get is an expression 0 = 0, which really doesn't help me.

Comment: Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502055/integration-of-eax-cos-bx-and-eax-sin-bx) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663131/integral-int-0-inftye-ax-cos-bx-operatorname-d-x) question and the related questions to these.

Comment: No. It's not the same question.

Comment: Consider $\Re\Big[\int_0^\infty \exp(-ax)\,\exp[i x)\,dx\Big]$

Comment: as an option - you can evaluate the integral (is has a simple closed form) and then find its maximum

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}\cos x dx
\end{equation}

You can use Laplace Transformation:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\cos{bt}dt
=\frac{s}{s^2+b^2}
\end{equation}

You can substitute values:
$s = a, b = 1$

$$\begin{align*}
f(a) = \frac{a}{a^2+1}
\end{align*}$$

Now, You want the value of $a$ for which $f(a)$ is max.

Differentiate the function and equate to zero:
$$\begin{align*}
f'(a)=\frac{d}{da}(\frac{a}{a^2+1}) = 0\\
=\frac{1-a^2}{(a^2+1)^2} = 0\\
\implies a =±1
\end{align*}$$

You can find the maximum value of is @ $a=1$ which is $f(a=1) = 0.5$

---

- Laplace Transform of $\cos{bt}$

Consider, $\cos{bt}=\operatorname{Re}\{e^{-ibt}\}$,
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-at}\cos(bt)\,dt=
\operatorname{Re}\int_0^\infty e^{-(a+ib)t}\,dt=
\operatorname{Re}\left[-\frac{e^{-zt}}{z}\right]_0^\infty=
$$
$$
\operatorname{Re}\left\{\frac{1}{z}\right\}=
\operatorname{Re}\left\{\frac{a-ib}{||z||^2}\right\}=
\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}.
$$

---

[image]

You can substitute your values:

As $x\to\infty$ it $\to0$

Comment: is it possible to do without laplace transform?

Comment: @JohnnyDang Yes! I could remember the integration of question
You can integrate the above-using integration parts or product rule:
You can [refer this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-spJ5Xadfc)
as $x \to\infty$ it will be zero because $e^{-ax}$ so just values of integration at $x=0$ will have to be checked>
I'll try to add in the above answer may take time.

Comment: Hm, i want to find the value for a that makes the integral the max value. And a has to be greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

define:
$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\cos(x)dx\qquad J=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\sin(x)dx$$
then:
$$K=I+iJ=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax} e^{ix}dx=\int_0^\infty e^{(i-a)x}dx$$
$$I=\Re(K)$$
now $K$ should be very easy to solve, multiplying by the complex conjugate of the bottom yields:
$$K=\frac{a+i}{a^2+1}$$
$$I=\Re(K)=\Re\left(\frac{a+i}{a^2+1}\right)=\frac{a}{a^2+1}$$
and conveniently you simultaneously work out the value of $J$