# Clarification $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}\cos (bx)\operatorname d\!x$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}\cos (bx)\operatorname dx \ \ ,\ \ a >0$

I would be grateful if someone could give me an explanation about Brightsun solution.

First $\gamma$ is that area ?
[image]

Second , how he get the third peace $\int_{\mathcal{R}}^0 \mathrm{d}r e^{i\omega}e^{-Are^{i\omega}}$ ?
The solution:

Let us integrate the function $e^{-Az}$, where $A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ on a circular sector in the first quadrant, centered at the origin and of radius $\mathcal{R}$, with angle $\omega$ which satisfies $\cos \omega = a/A$, and therefore $\sin \omega = b/A$.
Let this sector be called $\gamma$.

Since our integrand is obviously holomorphic on the whole plane we get:
$$
\oint_\gamma \mathrm{d}z e^{-Az} = 0.
$$
Breaking it into its three pieces we obtain:
$$
\int_0^\mathcal{R}\mathrm{d}x e^{-Ax}+\int_0^\omega \mathrm{d}\varphi i\mathcal{R}e^{i\varphi}e^{-A\mathcal{R}e^{i\varphi}}+\int_{\mathcal{R}}^0 \mathrm{d}r e^{i\omega}e^{-Are^{i\omega}}=0.
$$
The mid integral, as $\mathcal{R}\to\infty$ is negligible. So:
$$
\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}xe^{-Ax}=\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r (\cos\omega+i\sin\omega)e^{-Ar(\cos\omega+i\sin\omega)}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{A}\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r(a+ib)e^{-r(a+ib)}
$$
$$
\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r(a+ib)e^{-ar} (\cos br - i\sin br) = 1
$$
Now let's call $I_c = \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}re^{-ar}\cos br$ and $I_s = \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}re^{-ar}\sin br$, then:
$$
aI_c-iaI_s+ibI_c+bI_s=1
$$
and by solving:
$$
aI_c+bI_s=1;\ \ \ \ -aI_s+bI_c=0
$$
$$
I_c=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}; \ \ \ \ I_s=\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}.
$$
This method relies only on the resource of contour integration as you asked!

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/679436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First $\gamma$ is that area ?

No, $\gamma$ is not the area. $\gamma$ refers to the "closed and oriented circumference" (with direction counter-clockwise) of this sector. You can think of walking along the edge on the circumference with the orientation counter-clockwisely, and start from the origin point $O$ and travel a full cycle back to the origin. In complex analysis, we call this "closed path" as "contour".

> Second , how he get the third peace $\int_{\mathcal{R}}^0 \mathrm{d}r e^{i\omega}e^{-Are^{i\omega}}$ ?

> $$
> \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}xe^{-Ax}=\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r (\cos\omega+i\sin\omega)e^{-Ar(\cos\omega+i\sin\omega)}
> $$

Expand the exponential function using Euler's formula.

> $$
> \frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{A}\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r(a+ib)e^{-r(a+ib)}
> $$

Integrate the LHS, then substitute and replace $\sin\omega, \cos\omega$ with $a, b$.

> $$
> \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r(a+ib)e^{-ar} (\cos br - i\sin br) = 1
> $$

Use Euler's formula again, to expand the exponential function.

> Now let's call $I_c = \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}re^{-ar}\cos br$ and $I_s = \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}re^{-ar}\sin br$, then:
> $$
> aI_c-iaI_s+ibI_c+bI_s=1
> $$

Define the two integrals as $I_c, I_s$, so you get a algebraic equation.

> and by solving:
> $$
> aI_c+bI_s=1;\ \ \ \ -aI_s+bI_c=0
> $$

Let the real part equal the real part, and let the imaginary part equal the imaginary part. So you get two equations with two unknowns $I_c, I_s$

> $$
> I_c=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}; \ \ \ \ I_s=\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}.
> $$

Finally you solve the two equations and get the answer. The trick in this method is you don't need to do any integrations. You get the result by solving two algebraic equations.

Comment: Thanks , how he got $\frac{1}{A}$ in the RHS of the step $\frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{A}\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r(a+ib)e^{-r(a+ib)}$?

Comment: He just re-wrote $\cos \omega = a/A$, and $\sin \omega = b/A$, then take the factor $1/A$ out of integral.